# How would I get the name of the parameters in a function

Tags: c++, reflection, parameter-passing

I have a function

```
void print(stack<T>& One, stack<T>& Two, stack<T>& Three);
```

and I would like to output the parameter names (i.e. cout << "One")

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you want to print just the names of the output parameters, what you have mentioned should work. Is there is more to your question than what you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the compiler might not even keep the parameter names in the generated object files.  The symbols may be stripped away, or the parameters may be optimized away altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << ##One; //Outputs "One"
cout << ##Two; //Outputs "Two"
cout << ##Three; //Outputs "Three"
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/ and search for ##.

The macro ## replaces the following symbol with text. so ##One becomes "One" in the preprocessor step.